# brew link boost to homebrew python

Tags: python, boost, homebrew, boost-python

After installing boost with brew using the system layout option `--layout=system` (set using `brew edit boost155`)

`brew install boost155 --with-python --with-mpi --without-single`

I discovered that my boost library talks to the osx python, not the homebrew version

```
$ otool -L `brew list boost155 | grep python.dylib` | grep -i python 
/usr/local/Cellar/boost155/1.55.0_1/lib/libboost_mpi_python.dylib:  
   /usr/local/opt/boost155/lib/libboost_mpi_python.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)   @loader_path/libboost_python.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
   /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.0) 
   /usr/local/Cellar/boost155/1.55.0_1/lib/libboost_python.dylib:   /usr/local/opt/boost155/lib/libboost_python.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)  
  /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.0)
```

How can I link boost to the homebrew python libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the Homebrew Python. The system Python framework is in /System/Library/Frameworks.

Comment: How can I install boost with specified system python not the python from Homebrew?